# How to iterate over two lists of different length without combining them

Tags: python, list, loops, compare

Is there a way to iterate over two lists of different length at the same time without combining them?

I tried `itertools.product(list1, list2)` but that's very similar to a nested loop. So the second list gets iterated for each item of the first list, which is not what I want.

I want to compare both lists and see if they match.

Comment: How about [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)?

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to check for differences, you can use `set`s.
Let's say you have two lists, like

```
a=["one", "two", "three"]
b=["one", "other"]
```

You can check the difference by converting them to set:

`print(set(a) - set(b))`

The order matters: the first item is the one you are checking against the second:

`print(set(a) - set(b))` 
returns `{'three', 'two'}` (the items present in the first set that are missing in the second), while

`print(set(b) - set(a))` 
returns `{'other'}`

Comment: @random-xyz does order matter in your comparisons? How about duplicates? I recommend editing your post to show examples of what you're trying to do.